# Javascript URL Regex issues

Tags: javascript, regex

I use this regex for URL's:

```
var re = /^(http[s]?:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1}/;
```

However, it seems to only be matching URL's that are alone. If you add a URL to an already typed message, it won't match:

```
Test message: www.google.com
```

Won't match. How do I make it match URL's no matter what's included with them?

Comment: `{0,1}` should be `?`. Further you should keep [international domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) and long top-level domains like [.berlin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.berlin) in mind.

Comment: -1: If you're going to use regular expressions you should at least have *some* clue how they work. At least the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `^` character at the beginning of the expression means "match the beginning of the string" (in other words, what you have is a **starts-with** search).  Remove that and it will match anywhere in the test string.

```
var re = /(http[s]?:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1}/;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's simply because you're using the caret symbol (`^`). That means "only match the start of input." Remove that and you should get what you want.